# electron-build "not allowed to load local resource" but file exists

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have a normal Electron app, with a BrowserWindow that loads a file:

```
win = new BrowserWindow(...);
win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.resolve(__dirname, 'main.html'),
    protocol: "file:",
    slashes: true
}));
```

I'm using electron-build to package the app. Most of the time this works fine. But occasionally when I build it, both for Mac and Windows, the BrowserWindow doesn't load the file, and shows an error in the console:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///path/to/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/dist/main.html
```

In the developer tools' Network panel, it says `(blocked:other)` under Status.

But unlike many similar questions here, THE FILE EXISTS (in the asar archive). I can do this immediately after opening the window:

```
console.log(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'main.html'), { encoding: 'utf-8' }));
```

and it will print the file's contents.

I can see the file in the asar, at the expected path:

```
$ asar list /path/to/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar | grep main.html
/dist/main.html
```

So why won't it read the file? How can I debug this?

For what it's worth, my code is in `myproject/dist`, and in `myproject/package.json`, I have:

```
  "build": {
    "directories": {
      "output": "out"
    },
    "files": [
      "dist"
    ],
    ...
  }
```

I'm using the latest versions of electron and electron-builder as of now, but I've had the issue on earlier versions.

I tried using a file path instead of a URL:

```
win.loadFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'main.html'));
```

but got the same result.

I also tried using `"asar": false`. I get the same error, just with "app" instead of "app.asar" in the path. And the path points to a valid, readable file.

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured it out. I'd forgotten I was intercepting the `file:` protocol with `protocol.interceptFileProtocol`. My app name has a space in it, so when I called the `callback` function, and didn't replace the `%20` with an actual space, it couldn't find the file. Hope this helps someone.